# How to read subfolders files of same name in a folder in python?

Tags: python, list, directory, operating-system, dataset

I couldn't find a suitable answer so I asked here.
My folder organized like this:

```
F:\WORKS\dataset\SOB\ben
```

and "ben" has three sub-folders "ad", "fib" & "pot". And all these subfolders have a same subfolder named 'XC' in them. 'XC' has different type of ".png" files. No, I want to read all the "XC" subfolders ".png" files at once with python.

Is that possible? I need this because I have to relocate all "XC" subfolders file at one place.

Thanks.

I have tried to Solve it, but furthest I can get to relocate all ".png" files for 'ben' folder at once.

The code I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import os 
from os import listdir
from tqdm import tqdm
import shutil


%matplotlib inline


os.mkdir('augmented')
os.mkdir('augmented/ben')


def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in listOfFile:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)
                
    return allFiles

files_ben = getListOfFiles('/content/drive/MyDrive/Works/dataset/SOB/ben')
for f in files_ben:
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        
        shutil.copy(f,'augmented/ben')
```

Comment: Can you please put the code you've tried? When you say "at once", did you mean multithreading?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati , I Provided the code above.
And yes, I meant multithreading.